# redirect https non-www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect:

> **https://example.com => https://www.example.com [not working]**
>
> **http://example.com => https://www.example.com [not working]**
>
> www.example.com => https://www.example.com [working]
>
> example.com => https://www.example.com [working]

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Virtualhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/test/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/test/error.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/test.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/test.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: @anubhava: I am using same documentroot in virtualhost settings. Please see updated question.

Comment: @SeanBright: I tried that solution as well. First it's redirecting to www and then again coming back to non-www and in this case getting `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]`? https must be off OR the host doesn't start with www AND it has to contain any character?

Comment: `First it's redirecting to www and then again coming back to non-www`: That's not happening in rule shown above. Do you have any other code/rule that is causing this?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use .htaccess at all if you have access to and can modify .conf files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked by this `.htaccess` config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```