# How to fix not found error when redirect to https://www is used with RewriteBase?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, redirect, https

I want any access to my website to redirect to `https://www.` but I have a RewriteBase.

Suppose my website is `example.com`, I want:

`example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

`http://example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

`https://example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

`https://www.example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

And my website files are located in a subfolder, so I have a RewriteBase which is for example:

`RewriteBase /~myuser/mysite`

My .htaccess file contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~myuser/mysite
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I referred to the following question to write my .htaccess file: [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

As a result, if I write on in a browser a url such as `example.com/page1` (which is a valid page), it redirects to `https://www.example.com/page1` however, I get the following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /page1 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I think the problem is caused by the `RewriteBase`, but I do not know how to fix it.

Note that when I access the website main url `https://www.example.com` all internal sub-links work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /~myuser/mysite
```

Simply I placed the RewriteBase at the end after the RewriteRule and now it works.