# How to fix multiple redirects in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website "example.com" was hosted on non-www site address, I changed the Site URL from "example.com" to "www.example.com" in WordPress setting and then I installed SSL certificate to my website. Now my website is being redirected from example.com to https://example.com to https://www.example.com. I just want redirection from example.com to directly https://www.example.com. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you may look into answers shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any difference, but if you want to do that you'll have to edit it in your installation files.