# htaccess redirect 301 relative path , redirects the url from https to http while https is required

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have simple lines in my htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /something/ /blog/something/
```

if i hit https://www.example.com/something/

it redirectes to http://www.example.com/blog/something/

i want https://www.example.com/something/ to https://www.example.com/blog/something/

it should use the https and not http

Comment: You can fix this in htaccess. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: please suggest how it can be fixed ?

Comment: look at comment above

Comment: i am not forcing https and www from htaccess but it being added by wpengine itself

Comment: Sorry i have not enough experience with wordpress. Perhaps someone else knows how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/blog/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: as we have different environments , I don' t want to hard code the domain but prefer relative path