# Implementing a check for user levels

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

I'm attempted to create a login authentication system using PHP. So far I've managed to query the DB to check if a username/password given by the user matches any rows in the DB. However I have a column in the DB named "isadmin" which stores a boolean value. I want to implement a check if true/false. Depending on the result depends on which php file is loaded (included).

EDIT: I have two php files, both containing the same HTML displaying the index page of a website. However, one php file is for regular users, the other is for admin users which will contain added features. When a user enters their username and password, I want a check for the user level of that login, Once the check is done it should show the appropriate php page.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Reg_User WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
$details = [
 'username' => $_POST['username'],
 'password' => sha1($_POST['password'])
];
unset($_POST['submit']);
$stmt->execute($details);
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user['user_id'];
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $_POST['username'];
    include 'index.php';
   }
   else {
    echo 'Sorry, your username and password could not be found Please <a href="login.html">try again 
    or register!</a>';
  }
```

Comment: Add it as an additional clause in WHERE.

Comment: Side note: Is this a live or going live site? I hope not.

Comment: If I add the additional clause, how do I determine which php file to include depending on what is found in the DB. E.g. How do I send it to index.php if isadmin returns false and how do I navigate an isadmin = true to an admin.php? and no this definitely isn't going live

Comment: I don't get what you're asking about "which php file to include...". What is it you want to do here exactly? You might also like to edit your question at the same time, explaining in more clearer detail. Edit: What isn't working or do you want us to do something else? @user2519350

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: I have two php files, both containing the same HTML displaying the index page of a website. However, one php file is for regular users, the other is for admin users which will contain added features. When a user enters their username and password, I want a check for the user level of that login, Once the check is done it should show the appropriate php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple if/else statement will do it.

```
if ($user["isadmin"]) {
    echo "Logged in as an admin.";
    #you can include your related php page here.
} else {
    echo "Logged in as an user.";
    #you can include your related php page here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no sanitizing of user input in your code, this is a must in a login system, try this after your login form.
**info:** I don't use PDO, $con is the MYSQLI connection.

```
<?php
// Handle log in
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Sanitize username input
$username = strip_tags($username);
$username = trim($username);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$username = urldecode($username);

// Sanitize password input
$password = strip_tags($password);
$password = trim($password);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
$password = urldecode($password);
}
?>
```

Your site should be set to https only, if it is ignore this link: [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) and you should be providing either a secure session cookie or a secure persistent cookie for users who are able to log in successfully. The code underneath this paragraph should be at the very top of your page before any html. This example is for time related persistent https secure cookie set to 1 day after which it will expire. You could use a session cookie but I find this annoys people if they frequent your site quite often, they don't want to have to log in again the same day if they close and reopen a browser or tab.

```
<?php
// All this code goes right at the top of your page before anything else!
function addcookie() {
global $condition;
if ($condition == "green") {
global $nameofcookie;
setrawcookie('loggedin', $nameofcookie, strtotime('+1 day'), '/', '', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://example.com/mypage');</script>";
}
}
?>
```

The above code is will set a secure cookie using a function because you only want it firing after a successful login. The name of the cookie really should be random and unique, something based on microtime would work well. Make sure it's not anything important which could identify the user!
**IMPORTANT:** the name of the cookie for reference should be created at the time of account creation and added to the users table so you can identify users and represent their login details.

Standard security measures should also include a separate table of the ip, time, date and username of who logged in. If your site is busy the table will fill quickly so you could set a cron job to clean old records to keep the size down, in that case you will need to add a column for datetime to identify the age of records.

Handling the login...

```
<?php
$condition = "red";
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$select_login = "select * from Reg_User where username='$username' and password='$password'";
$connect_login = mysqli_query($con, $select_login);
$rows_login = mysqli_num_rows($connect_login);
if ($rows_login == 0) {
// code here to handle failed logins, I would record them and use a 3 strike method
}

// Handle successful logins, add cookie
else {
while ($row_login=mysqli_fetch_array($connect_login)) {
// Retrieve cookie name here from table
$nameofcookie=$row_login['cookie'];
$condition = "green"; // This allows you to add the cookie
addcookie();
}
}
}
?>
```

Retrieving the cookie to authenticate users...

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) {
$cookie = $_COOKIE['loggedin'];
$select_authenticated_user = "select * from Reg_User where cookie='$cookie'";
$connect_authenticated_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_authenticated_user);
while ($row_authenticated_user=mysqli_fetch_array($connect_authenticated_user)) {
// Retrieve values here from table
$logged_in_user=$row_authenticated_user['username'];
$logged_in_admin=$row_authenticated_user['isadmin'];
// Resolve admin status
if ($logged_in_admin == TRUE) {
$type = "admin";
} else {
$type = "member";    
}
}
// Echo statement for logged in user with admin or not status, you could change the echo to a variable name if you want to use this in a specific place on your page.
echo "Welcome $logged_in_user<br/>
Type: $type
";
}
?>
```

Here's a link for obtaining IP's: [How to get the client IP address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)