# Symfony logout. Change target path protocol from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

My logout target path sends request by HTTP protocol. All on server works by HTTPS protocol. How to say that after logout redirect should be by HTTPS protocol?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you configured your `.htaccess` so it redirects http request to https? Like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this with Symfony 4.

1. Force HTTPS for an range of urls ([Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/force_https.html)) with "requires_channel":

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    access_control:
        # ...
        # catch all URLs starting with /api/user
        - { path: '^/api/user', roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

2. Doing this for one Action as Annotation ([Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/routing.html#routing-force-https)) with "schemes":

```
// src/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/user/logout-end", name="api-user-logoutEnd", schemes={"https"})
     */
    public function apiUserLogoutEnd()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It could be that "Logout" is https, but the following site is not. Then you can apply the methods on that route, too.