# www doesn't redirect to non www with https on

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My problem is when I type `example.com` or `www.example.com` in browser it redirect to `https://example.com` but when I type `https://www.example.com`, it doesn't redirect to `https://example.com`.

I want whatever may be the url http or https and www or non www, it always point to `https://example.com`.

I have used below url rewrite for htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/541091 - but invert the `!^www\.` to be `^www\.` and remove www from the final rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also make sure this should be your TOP MOST rule in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

This should redirect urls irrespective of either url has http or https OR url has www or no www in it TO https without www.