# Wordpress redirect www to https

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded a wordpress website to Google Cloud Platform using a VM instance.

I have made the redirection of http to https . Although I can not make the redirerction of www to https, using the method of .htaccess

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have used this code but doesn't word:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: You can try with the below code - 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: At this point, nobody can help you.  Also, you probably haven't searched this site too well.  There are at least a few answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: Hi sorry, I am also using cloudflare.

Comment: I used this code but does nothing 

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Will I need to restart the VM for the changes to apply?

Answer (score 0):

Change with the following

```
 RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

refer: https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I have made a Page Rule inside cloudflare and I redirect all the traffic from WWWW to non-WWW .

So it is solved.